# Use WMI query in VBA to get list of open files on local computer

Tags: vba, wmi

As per title.  Using [this code example](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/02/16/how-can-i-list-open-sessions-and-open-files-on-a-computer/) (3rd example down) as my starting point.

Here's my effort at VBA code, but it stalls at the first hurdle ("Run time error 438: object doesn't support this property or method")

```
Sub Test()

    Set objConnection = GetObject("WinNT://HM10")

    Set colResources = objConnection.Resources

    For Each objResource In colResources

        Debug.Print objResource.Path

    Next

End Sub
```

HM10 is my computer name. Eventually it will need to be an environmental variable (if that's the right term) for whatever machine it happens to be on.

EDIT:  Ok, more searching has led me to this:

```
Sub test()

   Filename = "."

   Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

   qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE '%" & Filename & "%'"

   For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
     Debug.Print p.commandline
   Next

End Sub
```

which is closer,  but only shows local files, not network files.  I only need network files, how do I get them?

Comment: should be `WinNT://HM10/LanmanServer` - but that's only for open shares not any old open file.

Comment: Thanks, I no longer get error. But nothing prints.  How is an open share defined? And what is the LanmanServer?

Comment: If you share a folder over a LAN then the code will list details of which files within the shares are open in the sessions of other network users.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I've gone down the wrong path then.  Any thoughts on how I can get a list of the files open on my computer?  It's only files that are opened from our server that matter.  edit: server is a Synology Diskstation (linux based i believe)

Comment: @Alex K., I've made progress (see code added to original question) but this only includes local files, not those on the network (which are the ones I need!).